# Encrypting guest VM on ESXI with Veracrypt

Tags: veracrypt, vmware

Hi we're using an ESXI box to host some VM's locally on our network. We're devs and we just want things like UAT servers. We've encrypted with Veracrypt:

- Bitlocker was out as ESXI can't see the TPM.
- EXSI native encryption involved VSphere servers which seemed at bit beyond us.

So entering a password on boot seems fine for us in a dev environment. In terms of hard drives being lost or stolen are there any potential issues with this? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to encrypt the guest machines, then you can use veracrypt, but consider the performance impact. This way though you will need to enter a password every time the guest is restarted.

The other thing is, that if you create a snapshot of a running guest, then the encryption will be worthless.

Comment: I'm fine with the performance at the moment (we'll see how it goes) and the unattended boot in our situation is fine. The snapshot point is really good - I didn't think of that. We'll have to think of that. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any other problems regarding to lost/stolen drives.